# Makeindex - more than one definition for the same term

Tags: makeindex

I am using makeindex to create an index in a latex document. If I have an abbreviation, I include both the abbreviation and the full term, e.g.

```
\index{apple}\index{a|see{apple}}
```

But for some abbreviations, there may be two options for the full term.  If I just type:

```
\index{ant}\index{a|see{ant}}
```

I get an error.  Is there any way of coding it such that I get an index entry something like "a *see* ant *or* apple" (or something similar)?

Comment: \index{ant}\index{a|see{ant or apple}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\index{ant}\index{a|see{ant or apple}}
```

or

```
 \index{ant}\index{a|see{ant \textit{or} apple}}
```

Comment: Thanks - is there an easy way to give the "or" the same formatting as the "see"? At the moment, "see" is italicised, whilst "or" is plain text (like the index entry)

Comment: I am not sure it isn't the answer, unless author does explain further. Seems that this is what they want, except an italic or which is easily addressed as \index{ant}\index{a|see{ant \textit{or} apple}} - I'm not sure they are wanting anything more automated than that?

Comment: @HenriMenke This *is* the answer